# How was the legend of 7th game in tennis born?

Tags: trivia, tennis, history

Watching tennis on TV, it often happens that the commentator talks about the importance of the 7th game of the set; the player who wins that game has more probability to win the set.

This theory seems to be outdated nowadays, but I was interested in the origin of this theory.

Comment: I got a link about [the importance of 7th game](http://www.patcash.co.uk/2013/04/5-steps-to-master-the-vital-7th-game/)

Comment: this interesting article debunks the myth of the 7th game: http://www.tennisabstract.com/blog/2015/09/24/how-important-is-the-seventh-game-of-the-set/

Comment: IIRC this theory is often mentioned in connection with [Bill Tilden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Tilden)'s name.

Comment: I am not sure of the origin but I have heard the 7th game was called "jeu de Lacoste" - "Lacoste's game". René Lacoste must have had some theory about it - whoever wins the 7th game wins the set.

Answer (score 0):

While various factors have led me to stop following tennis closely, in younger years I followed it quite closely. I remember [Bud Collins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bud_Collins) mentioning the importance of a set's seventh game several times while commentating for NBC during tennis matches, especially Wimbledon. However, I don't remember any explanation of where the idea came from. While researching this answer, I found that BBC commentator [Dan Maskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Maskell) also frequently promoted the idea that the seventh game of a set is of crucial importance, but since I was watching & listening from the U.S., I was unfamiliar with Maskell.

As best as I can find Martin's comment seems to have this correct. The [Tennis Abstract blog article](https://www.tennisabstract.com/blog/2022/12/07/the-tennis-128-no-7-bill-tilden/) about [Bill Tilden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Tilden), states that the seventh game is sometimes called the "Tilden game" because he stated that the game was so important. That article caused me to find a free version of [The Art of Lawn Tennis](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1451/pg1451-images.html), in which Tilden stated:

> In the game score the sixth, seventh, and eighth games are the crux of
> every close set.

He then provides an example of a best of three doubles match that turned around when one side had a 1-0 set advantage and was serving at 5-1 but was broken and then fell apart.